# Using D3 in Modular ES6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, es6-modules, es6-class

I'm trying to "drag a dot" (an svg circle) using D3's drag functionality.  To keep things modular, I have multiple files.  Instantiating a dot, from a "Dot class" file, in an "App.js" file works!  HOWEVER, the drag behavior falls flat.

I've been at this for awhile, tinkering and "googling".  Pulling hair, now. I need a second set of eyes, please.  What am I getting wrong?

Thanks!

Dot.js:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

export class Dot {
  constructor(cx, cy, rad){
    this.cx = cx;
    this.cy = cy;
    this.radius = rad;
    this.svg = null;
    this.dot = null;
    this.width = 199;
    this.height = 533;
  }

  buildDot(){
    this.dot =
    d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width",this.width)
        .attr("height",this.height)
        .append("circle")
          .attr("cx",this.cx)
          .attr("cy",this.cy)
          .attr("r",this.radius);

    return this.dot;
  }

  onDrag(){
    console.log("dragging");
  }
}
```

App.js:

```
import {Dot} from './js/Dot';
import * as d3 from "d3";

(function(){

  var dot = new Dot(200, 200, 99).buildDot();
  console.log(dot);
  dot.call(d3.drag().on("drag", dot.onDrag));

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So, the problem was that when I "built" the `dot`, I was subsequently asking the `drag` eventlistener to call `onDrag` on the `dot` element.  This is, I was not calling the `onDrag` method from the "Dot" class instance.

So much time... I needed a sanity check way before I came here.